# Problem submitting iOS app created using react native

Tags: react-native

I created a react native app, ran  eas build --platform iOS

then ran

eas submit -p iOS

I also tried using Transporter.

here's the output and error:

```
andrewtriboletti@andrews-mbp JawnSocial % eas submit -p ios

Ensuring your app exists on App Store Connect. This step can be skipped by providing ascAppId in the submit profile.
Learn more: https://expo.fyi/asc-app-id

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … andy.triboletti@gmail.com
› Restoring session /Users/andrewtriboletti/.app-store/auth/andy.triboletti@gmail.com/cookie
› Team GreenRobot LLC (779S839979)
› Provider GreenRobot LLC (12273)
✔ Logged in Local session

✔ Bundle identifier registered com.greenrobot.JawnSocial
✔ Prepared App Store Connect for JawnSocial com.greenrobot.JawnSocial
✔ What would you like to submit? › Select a build from EAS
✔ Which build would you like to submit? › - ID: b09b94ac-adf9-43ef-b2be-3aab0d3f1ec0 (1 hour ago)
Looking up credentials configuration for com.greenrobot.JawnSocial...
✔ Select what to use for your project: › [Add a new ASC API Key]
✔ Generate a new App Store Connect API Key? … yes
✔ Created App Store Connect API Key.
✔ Created App Store Connect API Key
✔ App Store Connect API Key assigned to JawnSocial: com.greenrobot.JawnSocial for EAS Submit.
Using API Key ID: 6W4JT5AB87 ([Expo] EAS Submit TpemZYAU_k)

ASC App ID:                 1659700891
Project ID:                 b2792c43-f381-4595-bec4-029e735b6758
App Store Connect API Key:  
    Key Name  :  [Expo] EAS Submit TpemZYAU_k
    Key ID    :  6W4JT5AB87
    Key Source:  EAS servers
Build:                      
    Build ID    :  b09b94ac-adf9-43ef-b2be-3aab0d3f1ec0
    Build Date  :  12/13/2022, 1:42:44 PM
    App Version :  1.0.0
    Build number:  1

✔ Scheduled iOS submission

Submission details: https://expo.dev/accounts/andyt443/projects/JawnSocial/submissions/f4dc0e5c-8e69-48f7-8b9e-c35a83a478d3

Waiting for submission to complete. You can press Ctrl+C to exit.
✖ Something went wrong when submitting your app to Apple App Store Connect.

We couldn't figure out what went wrong. See logs to learn more.

[logs] Starting the submit process
[logs] Downloading archive
[logs] Preparing artifact
[logs] Verifying archive
[logs] Creating ascApiJsonKey.json file with ASC credentials
[logs] Submitting iOS app to TestFlight...
[logs] Submitting the app with fastlane pilot
[logs] -------------------
[logs] --- Step: pilot ---
[logs] -------------------
[logs] Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
[logs] Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 1659700891)...
[logs] Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[logs] This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[logs] [altool] 2022-12-13 13:11:05.326 *** Error: The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '1659700891' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 69084673-477e-4fd0-ab0d-06f50581a67f) (409)
[logs] [altool]  {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     NSLocalizedDescription = "The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "'1659700891' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 69084673-477e-4fd0-ab0d-06f50581a67f)";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     "original_server_error" =     {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         code = "ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.INVALID";
[logs] [altool]         detail = "'1659700891' is not a valid ID for this relationship.";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         id = "69084673-477e-4fd0-ab0d-06f50581a67f";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         source =         {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]             pointer = "/data/relationships/app/data/id";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         };
[logs] [altool]         status = 409;
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         title = "The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     };
[logs] 
[logs] [altool] }
[logs] Application Loader output above ^
[logs] Error uploading '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/ffc5114d-d1a8-43c6-81d9-ab4131a12c98.ipa'.
[logs] The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '1659700891' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 69084673-477e-4fd0-ab0d-06f50581a67f) (409)
[logs] The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[logs] Could not download/upload from App Store Connect!
[logs] [!] Error uploading ipa file: 
[logs]  [Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/ffc5114d-d1a8-43c6-81d9-ab4131a12c98.ipa'.
[logs] [Application Loader Error Output]: The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '1659700891' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 69084673-477e-4fd0-ab0d-06f50581a67f) (409)
[logs] [Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[logs] Fastlane pilot failed
[logs] Failed to submit the app
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to update my API key with EAS. Steps:

1. `eas credentials`
2. Select iOS
3. Select your build profile
4. Log into your account
5. Select "App Store Connect: Manage your API Key"
6. Select "Add a new API Key For EAS Submit"
7. When prompted, confirm that EAS should use the new key

The conversation over here helped me fix the issue:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20594

Answer (score -1):

I added

```
    "buildNumber": "1",
```

To app.json. Then it worked.

Comment: I added but not working